# How to reconnect a TcpClient as soon as network unplugged and then plugged

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I have a TcpClient that i want automatically re-connect as soon as network disconnects and then reconnect,but i am not getting how to achieve it..

Here is my function ..

```
  private void Conn()
    {

            try
            {
                client = new TcpClient();

                client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), intport));
                //Say thread to sleep for 1 secs.
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the error here.
                client.Close();
            }

            try
            {
                using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    byte[] notify = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello");
                    stream.Write(notify, 0, notify.Length);
                 }
                 byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                    while (true)
                    {
                        {
                            int numBytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                            if (numBytesRead > 0)
                            {
                                data= Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, numBytesRead);
                            }
                         }
                     }
               }
             catch{Exception ex}
```

Also how reliable is `while (true)` to get the continuous data from the Tcpip machine.Till my testing this codes automatically exits from responding or getting data after a while.
Please help me to get the uninterrupted data .
Thanks..

Comment: I think what you should do is check for client.Connected and if it returns false do the connect again

Comment: @Nokdu Nope this is not the way.I have checked it and its not reliable..

Answer (score 2):

You are immediately disposing of the `NetworkStream` after you have written something. This closes the socket. Don't do that. Rather, put the `TcpClient` in a `using` statement.

The way you read data is exactly right. The loop will exit when `Read` returns `0` which indicated a graceful shutdown of the connection by the remote side. If this is unexpected, the problem lies with the remote side.

Catch `SocketException` only and examine the status code property to find out the exact error.

It is not possible to reliably detect network errors. You have to wait for an exception to notice connection failure. After that, you need to periodically try establishing a connection again to find out when the network becomes available again.

I believe Windows provides some network interface level events to detect unplugged cabled but those are unreliable.